# Words for extrovert / introvert?

Tags: translation, single-word-requests

When I use the word "extrovert", I'm referring to someone who gains energy / recharges through social interactions.  Similarly, when I use the word "introvert", I'm referring to someone who gains energy / recharges by being alone or performing solo activities.

Is there a standard way in Esperanto to refer to these two concepts?

Answer (score 5):

The translations of the adjectives are *ekstravertita* and *introvertita*. The nouns are either *ekstravertito* and *introvertito* or *ekstravertulo* and *introvertulo*.

There is some disagreement about whether they should be *ekstraverta* and *introverta*, whether *ekstraverti* and *introverti* count as verbs or not, whether *eksteriĝema* and *eniĝema* would be better choices, etc.

The original Jungian meanings (finding meaning in life in outer events vs. inner events) conflict somewhat with the common ones of *societema* and *homevitema*.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of this information can be found in a decent on-line dictionary. Have a look, for example at the Reta Vortaro.

http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/ekstravert.html

http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/introvert.html

Comment: Thanks!  The Reta Vortaro looks really useful.  The dictionary I've been using so far (http://www.esperanto-panorama.net/vortaro/eoen.htm) has been pretty limited, and I haven't been able to find a lot of the words I've been looking for.

Comment: ReVo is good for finding words if you know the English word. It's always a good idea to cross-check in vortaro.net or somewhere else.